# Internet speed and bandwidth usage

Tags: c#, network-programming, network-interface

Here is the problem: I need to write a program, which will measure my internet speed and how much of it my computer is currently using and put it into a line chart with two series. Guided by google and posts on stackoverflow, I ended with this code:

```
private long bytesReceivedPrev = 0;
    private void CheckBandwidthUsage(DateTime now)
    {
        NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        long bytesReceived = 0;
        foreach (NetworkInterface inf in interfaces)
        {
            if (inf.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up &&
                inf.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback &&
                inf.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Tunnel &&
                inf.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Unknown && !inf.IsReceiveOnly)
            {
                bytesReceived += inf.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived;
            }
        }

        if (bytesReceivedPrev == 0)
        {
            bytesReceivedPrev = bytesReceived;
        }
        long bytesUsed = bytesReceived - bytesReceivedPrev;
        double kBytesUsed = bytesUsed / 1024;
        double mBytesUsed = kBytesUsed / 1024;
        internetUsage.Add(now, mBytesUsed);
        if (internetUsage.Count > 20)
        {
            internetUsage.Remove(internetUsage.Keys.First());
        }
        bytesReceivedPrev = bytesReceived;
    }

    private void CheckInternetSpeed(DateTime now)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri URL = new Uri("http://sixhoej.net/speedtest/1024kb.txt");
        double starttime = Environment.TickCount;
        client.DownloadFile(URL, Constants.GetAppDataPath() + "\\" + now.Ticks);
        double endtime = Environment.TickCount;

        double secs = Math.Floor(endtime - starttime) / 1000;

        double secs2 = Math.Round(secs, 0);

        double kbsec = Math.Round(1024 / secs);

        double mbsec = kbsec / 100;

        internetSpeed.Add(now, mbsec);
        if (internetSpeed.Count > 20)
        {
            internetSpeed.Remove(internetSpeed.Keys.First());
        }
        client.Dispose();
        try
        {
            // delete downloaded file
            System.IO.File.Delete(Constants.GetAppDataPath() + "\\" + now.Ticks);
        }
        catch (Exception ex1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex1.Message);
        }
    }
```

Problem is, that when I download some large files from internet (for example blender installer via web browser), the internet speed series is getting below my internet usage series. (see picture)
[image: anomalies in my internet meter]
Frankly, I don't uderstand this topic very well and don't really know in what direction should I go.

Comment: You're downloading a file as a speed test for "Internet speed", and it makes sense that that download is slower (ie the "Internet speed" curve goes down) if you're using the network more for other things.

Comment: Ok, so is there another way to check internet speed?